# Recursion search in python

Tags: python, recursion

I've been trying to wrap my head around the following recursion problem, but it doesn't quite work yet and I am out of ideas..

So, we have a dictionary, e.g.

```
main_dict = {a : [b,c,d], b: [c,d],d : [e,f]}...
```

Using recursion, I am trying to obtain the number of levels between two elements, for e.g. a:b = 1, a:d = 1, b:d = 1, a:e = 2, and so on.

my current code:

```
def depth(first, second):
    max_d = 0
    for element in main_dict[first]:
        if element != second:
            max_d += depth(element, second)
        else:
            return 1
    return max_d + 1
```

This returns correct results for some elements, but not all.

Comment: Why is the distance from a to e 2? How do you calculate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you add the depth multiple times, not only when it works. Also you don't check to verify that the key is in the dictionary, although I assume that your dictionary that you're actually using does in fact contain all the keys.

You could do a depth first search, where you loop through each element in the list at the key you're searching. If it's the second, return one, as you do, otherwise, check the items under it. You'll want to keep track of the keys you've checked so you don't check multiple times. When you check the items in the list, you want to return two things--if 'second' was found, and if so, how far down.

Say you're doing 'a' as first and 'e' as second. The elements in the list for 'a' are:

```
[b, c, d]
```

b is not e, so we'll look at the items under b:

```
[c,d]
```

c is not e, so we'll look at the items under c (you don't provide them in your answer, so I'll just assume e isn't there).
d is also not e, so we'll look at the items under d:

```
[e,f]
```

We found e, so now we return both that we found it, and that the depth was two (which we can keep track of by passing the depth as a parameter to the function).
Below is a function which does what I've described (it gives the answer of a:e as 3, but that's what it should be, going by what you've said):

```
main_dict = {'a' : ['b','c','d'], 'b': ['c','d'], 'd' : ['e','f']}

def search(a, b, cur_depth=0):
    for e in main_dict[a]:
        if e == b:
            return (True, cur_depth + 1)
        else:
            if e in main_dict:
                found, res = search(e, b, cur_depth=cur_depth + 1)
                if found:
                    return (True, res)

    return (False, -1)

print(search('a', 'b'))
print(search('a', 'e'))
```

Comment: Thabks, that clarified it for me.